# Use OpenSSL in C++Builder

Tags: openssl, rsa, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I'm compiling an app in C++Builder 10 Seattle, and trying to use OpenSSL for RSA work.

I followed this tutorial:

[How to Use OpenSSL to Generate RSA Keys in C/C++](http://www.codepool.biz/how-to-use-openssl-generate-rsa-keys-cc.html)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

bool generate_key()
{
    int             ret = 0;
    RSA             *r = NULL;
    BIGNUM          *bne = NULL;
    BIO             *bp_public = NULL, *bp_private = NULL;

    int             bits = 2048;
    unsigned long   e = RSA_F4;

    // 1. generate rsa key
    bne = BN_new();
    ret = BN_set_word(bne,e);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_all;
    }

    r = RSA_new();
    ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(r, bits, bne, NULL);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_all;
    }

    // 2. save public key
    bp_public = BIO_new_file("public.pem", "w+");
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bp_public, r);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_all;
    }

    // 3. save private key
    bp_private = BIO_new_file("private.pem", "w+");
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bp_private, r, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // 4. free
    free_all:

    BIO_free_all(bp_public);
    BIO_free_all(bp_private);
    RSA_free(r);
    BN_free(bne);

    return (ret == 1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    generate_key();
    return 0;
}
```

When I added `libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib` to my project, I got an error message:

> [ilink32 Error] Error: 'C:\USERS\ERICWANG\DESKTOP\TESTOPENSSL2\LIB\LIBEAY32.LIB' contains invalid OMF record, type 0x21 (possibly COFF)

I've seen some tips like using `coff2omf` and `implib` tools, but both didn't work.

1. I used `coff2omf.exe` to convert `libeay32.lib`. I put `coff2omf.exe` and `libeay32.lib` in the same folder, and entered this command:

   ```
   coff2omf libeay32.lib Blibeay32.lib
   ```

   It said:

   > ERROR: COFF error: libeay32.lib  : invalid machine type detected
2. I tried to convert `libeay32.lib` to a `.dll` file using `implib.exe`. I entered this command:

   ```
   implib libeay32.lib Blibeay32.dll
   ```

   It said:

   > Error : unable to open file

   And my `libeay32.lib` change its size to 1KB file. Which means the file was wrong.

Comment: There is no **XE10**. There is **10.0 Seattle**, **10.1 Berlin**, etc.

Answer (score 7):

OpenSSL works just fine in C++Builder.  I use it in my own C++Builder apps.

You cannot use the `.lib` files that are included with the pre-compiled OpenSSL DLLs.  Those `.lib` files are meant for Visual Studio.

In C++Builder, you need to use C++Builder's `implib` or `mkexp` command-line utility to create C++Builder-compatible import libs from the DLLs.  Use `implib` for 32bit DLLs and `mkexp` for 64bit DLLs.

It works fine, I have been using this technique for years when new OpenSSL versions are released.

Your `implib` command is wrong.  You cannot "*convert `libeay32.lib` to a `.dll` file*". The first parameter is an **output** parameter, the second parameter is an **input** parameter.  You need to **create** a `.lib` file for an **existing** DLL.  There is no `Blibeay32.dll` file, which is why you are getting the "*unable to open file*" error.  Drop the `B` and use the correct DLL filenames:

```
implib libeay32.lib libeay32.dll
implib ssleay32.lib ssleay32.dll
```

```
mkexp libeay32.a libeay32.dll
mkexp ssleay32.a ssleay32.dll
```

This will create `.lib` or `.a` files containing references for importing the functions from `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I take OpenSSL-Win64\bin\libeay32.dll to convert it to .lib .
But I use "implib libeay32.lib libeay32.dll".
There is no error message , also it create a 1KB size libeay32.lib file.
Still wrong.

Comment: [`implib.exe`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IMPLIB.EXE,_the_Import_Library_Tool_for_Win32) is only for 32bit DLLs. For 64bit DLLs, you need to use [`mkexp.exe`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/MKEXP.EXE,_the_64-bit_Windows_Import_Library_Tool_for_C%2B%2B) instead.

Comment: Thanks! It created a new libeay32.lib successfully.
But when I add it to my project and compile, 
[ilink32 Error] Error: 'C:\USERS\ERICWANG\DESKTOP\TESTOPENSSL2\LIB\LIBEAY32.LIB' contains invalid OMF record, type 0x21 (possibly COFF)
, it happened again.

Comment: I will say it again - use `implib` for 32bit DLLs and `mkexp` for 64bit DLLs. Use `.lib` for 32bit and `.a` for 64bit. `ilink32` is 32bit, `ilink64` is 64bit. `.lib` is OMF, `.a` is ELF. C++Builder has never supported COFF (Delphi does, though). `ilink32` will not reject a `.lib` created by `implib`. `ilink64` will not reject a `.a` created by `mkexp`.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explaination.
I've converted  libeay32.dll  to  libeay32.a  by  mkexp  already.
How do I use  .a  file in my project? Just add it?

Comment: @kim you use it the same way you would use a `.lib` file in 32bit.