# Linking error in using OpenSSL 3.1.0 in C++ builder XE8

Tags: openssl, linker-errors, c++builder-xe8

I'm trying to integrate Openssl 3.1.0 to my C++ project in C++ builder XE8.
I tried each and every way to link lib file with my project but still getting error:

> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new' referenced from C:\USERS\ADMINISTRATOR\DOCUMENTS\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\PROJECTS\TEST223\WIN32\DEBUG\TEST223.OBJ

steps I followed:

1. downloaded the source code from openssl official page and extract it in local directory.
2. in mingw32 i have built the library using the source code by make and make install.
3. created the lib file from dll using implib.
4. copy that lib file to the lib folder created by built.
5. included the path of include folder to project->options->c++ compiler->directories and conditionals->include file search path.
6. added the path of library folder to project->options->c++ Linker-> additional linked Libraries.
7. also added the `-lAdvapi32 -L"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\openssl-3.1.0\lib" -lcrypto -lssl`   project->options->c++ Linker->additional options.

and build the project and says the same error.

I have tried following resources to solve the error but unable to solve it.

- [Use OpenSSL in C++Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582334/use-openssl-in-cbuilder/38599592#38599592)
- [Using Embarcadero 10.1 Berlin with OpenSSL (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731298/using-embarcadero-10-1-berlin-with-openssl-c)
- https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation
- http://shane.hydrus.net/documentation/tutorial/GeneratingBorlandCppLibraryFiles/index.html

Tagging @Remy Lebeau because I found your suggestions and ideas are more informative in terms of using in c++ builder.

Comment: Did you specify the `-a` option when running `implib`? Also, `ilink32` doesn't have a `-l` option ([documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_ILINK32_and_ILINK64_on_the_Command_Line)), so either `drop` the `-l` prefix, or else just add the actual lib files to your project instead.

Comment: Thanks @Remy Lebeau for prompt response.
Yes I have used "implib -af libcrypto-3.lib libcrypto-3.dll" .
Also I have libcrypto.a and libssl.a files when Built it from source code . So if I drop -l prefix then dreictly add which file in option libcrypto.lib or libcrypto.a ?

Comment: Also after rebuilding the library and just -a for implib instead of -af , 
removed -l prefix from the additional options and just added the the libcrypto-3.lib & 
libssl-3.lib to my project,

it compile successfully but now gives error "The program can't start because libcrypto-3.dll is missing from your computer"

Comment: If your lib files are named `libcrypto-3.lib` and `libssl-3.lib`, why did you try to link to them as `crypto` and `ssl`? As for the new error, did you put the two DLLs in the same folder as your compiled EXE (or any other folder on your machine's [search path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order))?

Comment: so what should I write in project options->c++ linker->additional options. libcrypto-3 or libcrypto-3.lib?
I'm bit new with c++ builder so " did you put the two DLLs in the same folder as your compiled EXE" can you please simplify this . I didn't get it .

Comment: Did you read the [ilink32 documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_ILINK32_and_ILINK64_on_the_Command_Line) I directed you to earlier? As for the DLLs, your project produces an executable file when compiled, it is saved in a folder on your PC. The two OpenSSL DLLs should be copied to that same folder. How much simpler can I make it?

Comment: wow! That's amazing ! thank a lot your answer solved the issue. Finally I can successfully compile and run it. 
thanks you so much again @Remy Lebeau . You are the best !

Comment: I'm trying to create own library which uses openssl library and followed all the steps but when I'm building it it gives me [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'ssl\MydllTest.lib' .
even I'm not sure why it is looking for ssl directory where as it is not present in any of the linking option. Can you help with this @RemyLebeau please.